# Why does installation of .NET Framework 4.51 causes 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types error in application targeted to ver 4 of framework

Tags: c#, .net

I'm working on a Winform application that targets the .NET 4 framework and I'm using SQL Server 2005 for my database.  Recently I started to get the following error when executing the Entity Framework SaveChange method:

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"} System.Exception {System.IO.FileNotFoundException}

I've spent a lot of time trying to figure this out and found that it seems to have something to do with the installation of the .NET Framework 4.5.1 on my machine.  If I remove 4.5.1 (granted I have to reinstall .NET 4 framework) all works fine again.  I noticed 4.5.1 seems to get installed into the 4.0X folder and replaces many files but I'm assuming a newer version of the Microsoft.SqlServer.Types is needed but not installed, is this a known issue and is there some kind of fix?

Thanks

Comment: you say you have to reinstall 4.0 to fix it, are you sure you're installing the "same" 4.0 as the 4.5.1? Aren't you simply installing 4.0 full vs 4.5.1. client profile?

Comment: I go into Program and Features and remove 4.5.1, once that has completed, I looked in the 4.0X folder and it was almost completely empty so from there I installed 4.03.  4.5.1 seems to use the same folder as 4.03.

Comment: Yes but "what" 4.03, it's not the version number that matters, there are multiple "different" 4.03, there is the client profile (a subset) and the full Framework (everything), my gut feeling is you had a 4.5.1 client profile, and when you removed it you installed a 4.0 full profile (which was less up to date, but did contain additional assemblies). Can you reinstall 4.5.1 making sure you download the full profile one and check if it fixes it for you?

Comment: @RonanThibaudau, 4.5.x does not even have Client Profile, as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Good point, didn't know that, quite glad it is always found it a silly concept!

Comment: The version of .NET 4 that I reinstalled was the same as what was installed with VS 2010 (MS .NET Framework 4 Multi-Targeting Pack.  After that was installed and my application was working again, to test my theory I installed the full 4.5.1 and the error message returned.

Answer (score 0):

For my application that also uses the entity framework I had to install [Microsoft System CLR Types for SQL Server 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/de-de/download/details.aspx?id=35580).

I don't know if this 2012 package will work with your SQL Server 2005, so just give it a try.